# Storing files inside BASH scripts

Tags: bash

Is there a way to store binary data inside a BASH script so that it can be piped to a program later in that script?

At the moment (on Mac OS X) I'm doing

```
play sound.m4a
# do stuff
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
SOUND <<< the m4a data, encoded somehow?
END
echo $SOUND | play
#do stuff
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base64 encode it. For example:

```
$ openssl base64 < sound.m4a
```

and then in the script:

```
S=<<SOUND
YOURBASE64GOESHERE
SOUND

echo $S | openssl base64 -d | play
```

Comment: Not really. `S=<<SOUND` might not do what you think it does (and in any case, the variable `S` will not contain the content of the here-doc).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is like riding a dead horse since this post is rather old, but I'd like to improve Sionide21 answer as his solution stores the binary data in a variable which is not necessary.

```
openssl base64 -d <<SOUND | play
YOURBASE64DATAHERE
SOUND
```

> Note: HereDoc Syntax requires that you don't indent the last 'SOUND'
>   and base64 decoding sometimes failed on me when i indented that
>   'YOURBASE64DATAHERE' section. So it's best practice to keep the Base64
>   Data as well the end-token unindented.

I've found this looking for a more elegant way to store binary data in shell scripts, but i had already solved it like described here. Only difference is I'm transporting some tar-bzipped files this way. My platform knows a separate base64 binary so I don't have to use openssl.

```
base64 -d <<EOF | tar xj
BASE64ENCODEDTBZ
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a Unix format called [shar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) (shell archive) that allows you to store binary data in a shell script.  You create a shar file using the `shar` command.

Comment: This answer needs improvement with an example.

Answer (score 2):

When I've done this I've used a shell here document piped through [`atob`](http://ctan.binkerton.com/ctan.readme.php?filename=tools/atob/btoa.c).

```
function emit_binary {
  cat << 'EOF' | atob
  --junk emitted by btoa here
  EOF
}
```

the single quotes around `'EOF'` prevent parameter expansion in the body of the here document.

`atob` and `btoa` are *very* old programs, and for some reason they are often absent from modern Unix distributions.  A somewhat less efficient but more ubiquitous alternative is to use `mimencode -b` instead of `btoa`.  `mimencode` will encode into base64 ASCII.  The corresponding  decoding command is `mimencode -b -u` instead of `atob`.   The `openssl` command will also do base64 encoding.

Comment: @Sionide: Follow the link for source code, or you could use `mimencode`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I wrote a long time ago that packs a choice executable into a bash script.  I can't remember exactly how it works, but I suspect you could pretty easily modify it to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Stub Creator 1.0\n";

unless($#ARGV == 1)
{
    print "Invalid argument count, usage: ./makestub.pl InputExecutable OutputCompressedExecutable\n";
    exit;
}

unless(-r $ARGV[0])
{
    die "Unable to read input file $ARGV[0]: $!\n";
}

my $OUTFILE;
open(OUTFILE, ">$ARGV[1]") or die "Unable to create $ARGV[1]: $!\n";

print "\nCreating stub script...";

print OUTFILE "#!/bin/bash\n";
print OUTFILE "a=/tmp/\`date +%s%N\`;tail -n+3 \$0 | zcat > \$a;chmod 700 \$a;\$a \${*};rm -f \$a;exit;\n";

close(OUTFILE);

print "done.\nCompressing input executable and appending...";
`gzip $ARGV[0] -n --best -c >> $ARGV[1]`;
`chmod +x $ARGV[1]`;

my $OrigSize;
$OrigSize = -s $ARGV[0];

my $NewSize;
$NewSize = -s $ARGV[1];

my $Temp;

if($OrigSize == 0)
{
    $NewSize = 1;
}

$Temp = ($NewSize / $OrigSize) * 100;
$Temp *= 1000;
$Temp = int($Temp);
$Temp /= 1000;

print "done.\nStub successfully composed!\n\n";
print <<THEEND;
Original size: $OrigSize
New size:      $NewSize
Compression:   $Temp\%

THEEND
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single block of data to use, the trick I've used is to put a "start of data" marker at the end of the file, then use sed in the script to filter out the leading stuff. For example, create the following as "`play-sound.bash"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '1,/^START OF DATA/d' $0 | play
exit 0
START OF DATA
```

Then, you can just append your data to the end of this file:

```
cat sound.m4a >> play-sound.bash
```

and now, executing the script should play the sound directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is available on OS X by default, you can do as below:

```
ENCODED=$(python -m base64 foo.m4a)
```

Then decode it as below:

```
echo $ENCODED | python -m base64 -d  | play
```